# Android studio getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer error in Marshmallow

Tags: web-services, android-studio, xampp, localhost, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to call webservices with **http://127.0.0.1/demo/**, but it does not work in Marshmallow. It gives the following error. My webservices is running into **XAMPP server**.

```
11-15 16:31:55.053 15702-15736/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaefef440
```

It works perfectly in Lollipop and Kitkat,

Please guide me, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an identified issue in Marshmallow. Checkout [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192357) link for details. They have fixed the issue in Android 6.0.1 which was released last year in December.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Android Studio and Emulator.