# Android Retrofit no response

Tags: java, android, json, rest, retrofit

HI I'm just new to retrofit service and followed this tutorial https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/ it works well and wanted to create my very own so i used a new json web 
http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/ that contains

```
{
"contacts": [
    {
            "id": "c200",
            "name": "Ravi Tamada",
            "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c201",
            "name": "Johnny Depp",
            "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c202",
            "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio",
            "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c203",
            "name": "John Wayne",
            "email": "john_wayne@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c204",
            "name": "Angelina Jolie",
            "email": "angelina_jolie@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "female",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c205",
            "name": "Dido",
            "email": "dido@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "female",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c206",
            "name": "Adele",
            "email": "adele@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "female",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c207",
            "name": "Hugh Jackman",
            "email": "hugh_jackman@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c208",
            "name": "Will Smith",
            "email": "will_smith@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c209",
            "name": "Clint Eastwood",
            "email": "clint_eastwood@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c2010",
            "name": "Barack Obama",
            "email": "barack_obama@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c2011",
            "name": "Kate Winslet",
            "email": "kate_winslet@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "female",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c2012",
            "name": "Eminem",
            "email": "eminem@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    }
]
```

I implemented my own interface ContactAPI.java

```
public interface ContactsAPI {
@GET("/contacts/")
public void getContacts(Callback<List<Contact>> response);}
```

And Implemented model class like this Contact.java

```
public class Contact {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;
@SerializedName("gender")
@Expose
private String gender;
public String getId() {return id;}
public void setId(String id) {this.id = id;}
public String getName() {return name;}
public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
public String getEmail() {return email;}
public void setEmail(String email) {this.email = email;}
public String getAddress() {return address;}
public void setAddress(String address) {this.address = address;}
public String getGender() {return gender;}
public void setGender(String gender) {this.gender = gender;}}
```

then finally implemented my Restadapter in MainActivity.class

```
  public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://api.androidhive.info";
  private ListView listView;
  private List<Contact> contacts;
   RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(ROOT_URL).build();
    ContactsAPI api = adapter.create(ContactsAPI.class);

    api.getContacts(new Callback<List<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Contact> list, Response response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,list.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            showList();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            //you can handle the errors here
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error Occured:"+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

The App runs smoothly but after a 4 seconds delay it will promt an error which is public void failure(RetrofitError error) i dont know what i'm missing i checked my code and can't find anything wrong pls help me thanks in advance.

Comment: whats the error message?

Comment: knowing the error would certainly help. Do you have the internet permission in the manifest ?

Comment: @Juvi - this is the error that comes to logs E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa9ef1b0

Comment: @Blackbelt - yes i do have the internet permission on the manifest and my error logs in E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa9ef1b0

Comment: It's a [known issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719149/android-studio-getslotfrombufferlocked-unknown-buffer-error-in-mashmallow) with Android 6.0. Fixed in 6.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the json is this you need a class with:

```
public class Contacts {
    @SerializedName("contacts")
    @Expose
    private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The contacts
     */
    public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param contacts
     * The contacts
     */
    public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

}
```

Also in your interface ContactAPI.java

```
public interface ContactsAPI {
    @GET("/contacts/")
    public void getContacts(Callback<Contacts> response);
}
```

Also check this link because there is a problem with "+", this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array)

Comment: thank you for replying sir but the only outcome that the given code yog gave to me is 

"Contact@824ec91"

Do i miss something?

Comment: Ok Now i get it the reason you provide the Contacts class is to provide a list for the object then i need to use my Contact class to call the parameters of the object thx to my friend and you i cut my development time in half thank you! Cheers!